# Change in default namespace and assembly name of a project. Does it affect project which reference it

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, .net-assembly

I have a solution with many projects in it. I want to change the default namespace and the assembly name of one of the projects since they are not the same as the project name and there is confusion while finding dlls. 
I did this by changing it in the properties of the concerned project.

Now I have a problem I want to only apply the hot fix for the project.
So will the project which reference it be able to identify it if I only change the dll of 1 project(whose name of dll has been changed) in the release. 
Or do I need to find all the projects which reference it and apply the hotfix for all those projects.

The referencing is project referencing not dll

Comment: I tried something like this too in a smaller project... I accepted the confusion and stopped converting

Comment: NB Changing the _default_ namespace won't update any _existing_ namespaces, so references to your existing namespaces shouldn't break. If you change your assembly name, anything using (an assembly reference to) your code will have to update its references to your assembly.

Comment: @Rawling Will I have to update other projects if the code is referenced using project references in one solution itself.

Comment: @puneet I would expect project references to be OK.

Comment: They are not, the display name they use in their manifest for the referenced project assembly will be wrong.  Contemplating a hotfix in this scenario is unwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hotfix indeed did not work and the other project dlls did not consider the change in name of the default namespace and the assembly name of the dll they were dependent on. So for anyone changing the default namespace or assembly name apply the whole set of dls which are dependent on dlls being changed